# Elastic search to match top level field, and a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't seem to get this query to work

I am trying to match all tags who's name matches $channel_name,
but also, which has a video, with the name of $search.

I think the nested part is messed up.  How can I fix this query?
[image]

```
$body = [
'query' =
    [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
                'match_phrase' => ['name' => $channel_name]

            ],
            'nested' => [
                'path' => 'videos',
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        [
                            'must' => [
                                'match' => [
                                    'videos.name' => $search
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]

                ]
            ]
        ],

    ],
'inner_hits' => [
    'videos' => [
        'path' => [
            'videos' => [
                'size' => $this->pageSize,
                'sort' => $sortOrder,
                'from' => ($pageNumber - 1) * $this->pageSize,
                'query' => [
                    'match_all' => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

]
```

];

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you get no results? Also please share the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/tags`?

Comment: please your schema mappings and few sample docs

Comment: Do you really need a nested datatype for this kind of information?

Comment: hi user3775217. the mapping is pasted in the question.